# Do I get Ore if I upgrade the Dig Site in my Garrison and how much?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

The Tooltip of the plan for the dig site says:

> The Mine was once abandoned, but there are still underground riches
>   ready to be discovered.
>
> - Level 1: Allows players to mine Draenic Stone from mineral nodes
>     in Draenor. Draenic Stone can be converted to work orders for Draenor
>     minerals. 7 Work Orders
> - Level 2: Allows followers with the Mining
>     trait to work here, granting a unique bonus (adds mining carts). Also
>     opens a new mineshaft, granting access to additional mining nodes. 14
>     Work Orders
> - Level 3: A final mineshaft allows access to rich
>     mining nodes. In addition, garrison guards will patrol your mine,
>     keeping it clear of hostile Goren. 21 Work Orders.

It does not say what I actually get. Do I get resources or ore? If I get Ore, how much per day? What are the exact benefits?

*I am Engineer so the Ore would be welcome, but I cannot harvest any ore since I am Jeweler with my second profession on my main character.*

Comment: This is really confusing. What do you mean "It does not say what I actually get" I can see clearly what they're going to give you. Can you help pinpoint that?

Comment: It gives me access to mining nodes which I cannot mine. But it also allows me to let followers work there. But what do they harvest? Actual Ore that I can use for my professions or resources that are garrison only? That is the important part. @Chantola

Comment: @NoneOfYourBuisness Ahh, got ya thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You will be able to mine even without the mining profession and you can earn ores, stones, and primal spirits for doing so.**

Icy-veins states that:

> **The ore nodes in your mine can be mined without having Mining as a profession.**
>
> Each of them contain either Blackrock Ore or True Iron Ore, a few Draenic Stones, and sometimes a few Primal Spirit. The nodes respawn every day (at the time when the daily quests are reset). The size of your mine increases as you upgrade it, so you have a lot more nodes in a Level 3 mine than you do in a Level 1 mine.
>
> To give you an idea, a Level 1 mine can provide you with 15-20 Blackrock Ore, True Iron Ore, and Draenic Stones a day. **A Level 3 mine with a follower can provide you with 150x Blackrock Ore, 150x True Iron Ore, and 50x Draenic Stone.**

Blackrock ore and True Iron Ore are actual crafting reagents, and can be used like other mining ores found in WoW. Primal Spirit's are actually a garrison item than can be given to your primal trader in your garrison in exchange for other various crafting reagents.

---

[Source](http://www.icy-veins.com/wow/garrison-lunarfall-excavation-frostwolf-mines-guide)

[Source 2](http://www.wowhead.com/item=120945/primal-spirit)

Comment: Don't forget to loot the carts!  They also contain ore, gray items, and mining buffs, but aren't marked on the minimap.

Comment: Those carts also contain Draenor archaeology fragments. The ability to harvest without the accompanying profession also applies to the Herb Garden when you unlock it.

Comment: A little tip. Before upgrading the mine (level 2 or level 3) or the garrison (level 3), make sure you have mined all nodes. They will re-spawn upon doing this. This may be patched out, but for now, every little helps. This also applies to the Herb Garden.

Comment: And also, Draenic Stone is currently only used for Mine Work Orders. This costs 5 per work order and will yield some ore and a chance at Apexis Crystals.